# How to move first 7 characters of a file name to the end using Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, file-rename, batch-rename, rename-item-cmdlet

My company has millions of old reports in pdf form. They are Typically named in the format: `2018-09-18 - ReportName.pdf`

The organization we need to submit these to is now requiring that we name the files in this format: `Report Name - 2018-09.pdf`

I need to move the first 7 characters of the file name to the end. I'm thinking there is probably an easy code to perform this task, but I cannot figure it out. Can anyone help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveat**:

- As [jazzdelightsme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8813306/jazzdelightsme) points out, the desired renaming operation can result in *name collisions*, given that you're removing the day component from your dates; e.g., `2018-09-18 - ReportName.pdf` and `2018-09-19 - ReportName.pdf` would result in the *same* filename, `Report Name - 2018-09.pdf`.
- Either way, I'm assuming that the renaming operation is performed on *copies* of the original files. Alternatively, you can create *copies with new names elsewhere* with `Copy-Item` while enumerating the originals, but the advantage of `Rename-Item` is that it will report an *error* in case of a name collision.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  $_.Name -replace '^(\d{4}-\d{2})-\d{2} - (.*?)\.pdf$', '$2 - $1.pdf' 
} -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.

Add `-Recurse` to the `Get-CildItem` call to process an entire directory *subtree*.

The use of `-Filter` is optional, but it speeds up processing.</sup>

- A *script block* (`{ ... }`) is passed to `Rename-Item`'s `-NewName` parameter, which enables dynamic renaming of each input file (`$_`) received from `Get-ChildItem` using a string-transformation (replacement) expression.
- The `-replace` operator uses a *regex* (regular expression) as its first operand to perform string replacements based on patterns; here, the regex breaks down as follows:

  - `^(\d{4}-\d{2})` matches something like `2018-09` at the start (`^`) of the name and - by virtue of being enclosed in `(...)` - captures that match in a so-called *capture group*, which can be referenced in the replacement string by its index, namely `$1`, because it is the *first* capture group.
  - `(.*?)` captures the rest of the filename *excluding* the extension in capture group `$2`.

    - The `?` after `.*` makes the sub-expression *non-greedy*, meaning that it will give subsequent sub-expressions a chance to match too, as opposed to trying to match as many characters as possible (which is the default behavior, termed *greedy*).
  - `\.pdf$` matches the the filename extension (`.pdf`) at the end (`$`) - note that case doesn't matter. `.` is escaped as `\.`, because it is meant to be matched *literally* here (without escaping, `.` matches *any* single character in a single-line string).
  - `$2 - $1.pdf` is the replacement string, which arranges what the capture groups captured in the desired form.

Note that any file whose name doesn't match the regex is quietly left alone, because the `-replace` operator passes the input string through if there is no match, and `Rename-Item` does nothing if the new name is the same as the old one.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ChildItem` with some RegEx and `Rename-Item` can do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" | foreach {

    $newName = $_.Name -replace '(^.{7}).*?-\s(.*?)\.(.*$)','$2 - $1.$3'
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
}
```

**The RegEx**

`'(^.{7}).*?-\s(.*?)\.(.*$)'` / `$2 - $1.$3`

- `(^.{7})` matches the first 7 characters
- `.*?-\s` matches any characters until (and including) the first found `-` (space dash space)
- `(.*?)\.` matches anything until the first found dot ( . )
- `(.*$)` matches the file extension in this case
- `$2 - $1.$3` puts it all together in the changed order

This won't properly work if there are filenames with multiple dots ( . ) in it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (added some test data):

```
$test = '2018-09-18 - ReportName.pdf','2018-09-18 - Other name.pdf','other pattern.pdf','2018-09-18 - double.extension.pdf'

$test | % {
    $match = [Regex]::Match($_, '(?<Date>\d{4}-\d\d)-\d\d - (?<Name>.+)\.pdf')
    if ($match.Success) {
        "$($match.Groups['Name'].Value) - $($match.Groups['Date'].Value).pdf"
    } else {
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but you can make this more PowerShell-idiomatic: `% { if ($_ -match '(?<Date>\d{4}-\d\d)-\d\d - (?<Name>.+)\.pdf') { "$($Matches.Name) - $($Matches.Date).pdf" } else { $_ } }` or, even more concisely, with `-replace`: `% { $_ -replace '(?<Date>\d{4}-\d\d)-\d\d - (?<Name>.+)\.pdf', '${Name} - ${Date}.pdf' }`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
Get-ChildItem -path $path | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.Split(' - ')[-1] + ' - ' + $_.BaseName.SubString(0,7) + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

**Explanation -**

1. `Split` will segregate the name of the file based on the parameter `-` and `[-1]` tells PowerShell to select the last of the segregated values.
2. `SubString(0,7)` will select 7 characters starting from the first character of the `BaseName` of the file.
3. Remove `-WhatIf` to apply the rename.

Comment: Be sure to check for collisions to avoid losing data (e.g. two reports, one from 2018-09-02 and one from 2018-09-28 would both get renamed to the same file). Consider writing the files to a new location instead of renaming (overwriting) the old files.

Comment: Even if it goes to a new location there will still be clashes in names, since the OP wants only the `YYYY-MM` part to be suffixed to the report name. So, a new location would also not suffice, I guess. Hence, provided the `-WhatIf` option.

Comment: Yes, but you won't [potentially irretrievably] lose data that way, and can easily check if you had any clashes, such as by checking the number of files in both locations.

Comment: This is close, but it is eliminating mostly all of the File Name. For instance, it is changing something named "2018-09-17 Report Name" to "Name - 2018-09" I need to keep the full report name